# Which JVM for Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, embedded, arm, raspberry-pi

I'm a little bit confused about the various ways to run Java programs on the Raspberry Pi.
As I see it there are the following possibilities:

Java 6:

- Java SE 6 Embedded

Java 7:

- OpenJDK 7
- Java SE 7 Embedded
- JDK 7.40 (and greater)

Java 8:

- JDK 8

This brings us to the following questions:

1. Is there a difference between the JVM shipped with JDK and Java SE?
2. Is there no ARM version of OpenJDK 6 or 8?
3. What are the benefits of Java SE 7 Embedded over the regular Java SE 7 VM (included in JDK 7)?
   I could only find the following points:

   - Low memory footprint
   - No AWT/Swing
4. Java SE 7.40 for Raspberry Pi
   The Oracle homepage only lists downloads for an ARM v6/v7 Soft Float ABI and an v7 Hard Float ABI version.
   As the Raspberry Pi uses the v6 architecture I guess you have to use the Soft Float version.
   So there should be no speed improvements over the Java SE 7 Embedded VM which also uses the Soft Float ABI, right?
5. Is there no embedded version of Java SE 8?
6. Does JDK 8 always use the Hard Float ABI or is there also a Soft Float ABI version?

To sum up:

- If you want to use the Hard Float ABI use the developer preview of JDK 8
- If you want a stable Java version with a low memory footprint use Java SE 7 Embedded
- If you want a stable Java version and want to use Swing/Awt use JDK 7.40 (and greater)

Comment: If you're worried about the performance differences between the soft and hard float ABI, you probably shouldn't be using Java in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Since September all the Raspbian images will ship (by default) with Oracle Java which is supposed to be optimized for Raspberry